# Make semantic_errors render the exact error-message

Tags: activeadmin, formtastic

I have a model `Camping` which `has_many` `Images`. At least one image is required on Camping:

```
class Camping < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :images_attributes
  has_many :images
  validates_presence_of :images, :message => "At least one image is required"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
 end
```

Then, in [active_admin](http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html), which uses [formtastic](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic), I render the error message **At least one image is required**, with `f.semantic_errors`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Camping do
  form :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
     f.semantic_errors :images
     #....
     f.inputs "Images" do
      f.has_many :images do |img|
        #....
      end
    end
    #....
  end
end
```

This renders as:

[image: Example output of error]

**Images At least one image is required**.

How can I make it render: **At least one image is required**?

changing the `f.semantic_errors :images` into '`f.semantic_errors` (removing :images) makes it render nothing; no error at all.

Note: The [API documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/Formtastic/Helpers/ErrorsHelper:semantic_errors) seems to imply that Formtastic always adds the `:attribute` name to the error; but I am not entirely sure how this code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use such custom messages you can add error messages that are related to the object’s state as a whole, instead of being related to a specific attribute

Change this

```
validates_presence_of :images, :message => "At least one image is required"
```

to something like

```
   validate :should_have_images
   def should_have_images
       errors.add(:base, "At least one image is required") if images.blank?
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use such custom messages you can add new method to `Formtastic::Helpers::ErrorsHelper` As follows

create new file at `config/initializers/errors_helper.rb`

Place following code to file

```
module Formtastic
  module Helpers
    module ErrorsHelper
      def custom_errors(*args)
        return nil if @object.errors.blank?
        messages = @object.errors.messages.values.flatten.reject(&:blank?)
        html_options = args.extract_options!
        html_options[:class] ||= 'errors'
        template.content_tag(:ul, html_options) do
          messages.map do |message|
            template.content_tag(:li, message)
          end.join.html_safe
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In activeadmin form use 
`f.custom_errors` instead of `f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys`

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question but that's what i needed, thx !
But if you want you can also keep the method naming `semantic_errors` and it will override the logic